# Why doesn't after() wait

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, timer

I'm new to Python and wanted to build a sleeptimer for training purposes.
I'm using Python 3.6.3 on Ubuntu.
I wanted a label which shows how many time is left till the Computer wents to sleep.

I'm using `after()` but every time I call the update Method it calls itself very often until I reach the maximum recursion depth with the **Error**:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

I think that, for some reason the `after(1000, self.update)` command doesn't wait 1 second before calling the method again. Also I don't want a recursion, but call the method each second...

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Application(Frame):

    def startTimer(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        self.waiting = self.entry.get()*60000
        self.update()
        self.after(self.waiting, self.shutdown)

    def update(self):
        string = str(int(int(self.waiting/6000) + self.start - time.time())/10)
        print(string)
        self.label.config(text = string + " Minuts left")
        self.after(1000, self.update())

    def shutdown(self):
        print("PSSST!")

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.entry = Scale(self, from_=5, to=120, orient=HORIZONTAL, resolution=5)
        self.label = Label(self,text="time remaining")

        self.start = Button(self, text="Start", fg="black",
                            command=self.startTimer)

        self.quit = Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=root.quit)

        self.entry.pack(side="top")
        self.label.pack(side="left")
        self.start.pack(side="right")
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()`
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
self.after(1000, self.update())
```

You are not passing the `self.update` function to `self.after`, you are calling `self.update()` immediately and passing the result to `self.after`. This causes infinite recursion.

Comment: Uhh thank you...
it works with 'self.after(1000, self.update)'